# Mongo: sort results with $in array parameter

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have two collections **users** and **items** and **user.profile.savedItems** is an array of items saved like so: {"itemId" : "yHud5CWpdPaEc6bdc",     "added" : ISODate("2014-09-12T22:28:11.738Z")}

What I am trying to do is to retrieve the items from the user profile (that part works) and to order them according to the *added* date.

Right now, this is the code that I have:

```
return {items: Items.find({_id: {$in: _.pluck(Meteor.user().profile.savedItems, 'item')}})};
```

I don't know if it's possible using regular mongo syntax..

Answer (score 1):

You have **two** options:

1. Store the items sorted.
2. Sort the items client-side after reading.

Read unsorted items sorted without client-side sorting is **not** possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
1. Right now, I am using addToSet and I searched and found the $position operator but it seems like it wouldn't work with addToSet. Although they are already naturally sorted, I just need it in reverse.
2. How would I do that since the items themselves don't have the "added" parameter?

Comment: Check out [this technique](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/#sort-array-of-documents-by-a-field-in-the-documents) for storing an array in inserted order.

Comment: Third option: place those items in a separate collection and sort them with Mongo.

Comment: So I tried inserting in order but it seems like meteor's minimongo is behind mongodb and the $sort won't work without $each.
But I thought of something else. Could I create a new clone collection of "items" and for each one add the extra property "added" by mapping the corresponding ids?